# Search Widget in Blog page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, widget

I have added search widget on my Blog page. when I click on blank search it filters out all the page of my website. I want to add setting using coding that it only filters out the blog post.

I have added this code for that

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

but using this code, by search product functionality stop working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Goto wp-includes/query.php
Find below and

```
$q[‘post_type’] = ‘any’;
replace
$q[‘post_type’] = ‘post’;
```

or better way to put this code in functions.php file to overcome the issue after any wordpress update

```
if (!is_admin()) {
function wpb_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```

Comment: It will lost when WordPress get updated if you change core files

Comment: if (!is_admin()) {
function wpb_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}